# Powershell: Use of Invoke-Expression to map a drive using Net Use

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to map a drive inside a Powershell script.  I need to pass a drive letter to a TSM script which is why im favouring this command.

I've written the command as:

```
Invoke-Expression "net use w: \\server\share\$($path) /user:domain\user"
```

`$path` is a variable containing the folder name

But it just hangs the Powershell window.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you invoke `net` directly: `net use w: "\\server\share\$path" /user:domain\user`?

Comment: again it just hangs the terminal

Comment: Hm it hangs the ISE but doesnt hang the powershell terminal.. Seems its not a syntax problem.

Comment: Now im getting System error 55 has occurred.

The specified network resource or device is no longer available.

Comment: I can map the the root of the share but not to a subdirectory